# Checking if a word exists in an alphabetical list using binary search

Tags: c#

I have a list of words, sorted in alphabetical order, and I need to check if a word that's been entered is in that list. Because this is a homework assignment, I have to use binary search for this. After figuring out that the word in the middle of the list is not the word I'm looking for, I can't figure out how to find which half of the list to look in next as I cant compare words. I don't know how I would go about this.

What I have so far (up to checking if midpoint = the word)
c#

```
private static bool CheckWordIsValid(string Word, List<string> AllowedWords)
       {
            bool ValidWord = false;

            int start = 1;
            int end = AllowedWords.Count;
            int mid = (int)((start+ end) / 2);
            string theword = Word;
            while (ValidWord == false)
            {
                if (AllowedWords[mid] == theword)
                {
                    ValidWord = true;
                }
            } 
            return ValidWord;
        }
```

Comment: What if you checked if the word is "greater than" or "less than" the middle word? Would that tell you which side to continue the search on?

Comment: That would, but the problem is that I don't know how; I can't just do > or < because they're words and not numbers

Comment: But `string` implements `IComparable`. That should be enough of a hint for you

Comment: [List<T>.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-7.0) and [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Collections.Immutable/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableList_1.Node.cs,11ad82e8ffdf3cdb)

Comment: See the Wiki algorithm : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 3):

To perform a binary search in a sorted list of words, you can compare the target word with the word at the middle index. If they are the same, you have found a match. If the target word is lexicographically smaller than the word at the middle index, you can continue the search in the first half of the list. If the target word is lexicographically greater, you can search in the second half of the list.

Here's an updated version of your code that implements the binary search algorithm correctly:

```
private static bool CheckWordIsValid(string word, List<string> allowedWords)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = allowedWords.Count - 1;

    while (start <= end)
    {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        int comparison = string.Compare(allowedWords[mid], word);

        if (comparison == 0)
        {
            // Word found
            return true;
        }
        else if (comparison < 0)
        {
            // Target word is greater, search in the second half
            start = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Target word is smaller, search in the first half
            end = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    // Word not found
    return false;
}
```